# Le nom d'Aristotélēs en français (Aristote : pourquoi pas de « l » ?)

Tags: orthographe, noms-propres, grec, évolution, écriture

En grec Ἀριστοτέλης (Aristotélēs) ; en anglais *Aristotle* ; en italien *Aristotele* ; en espagnol *Aristóteles* ; en allemand *Aristoteles* ; en roumain *Aristotel* ; or, en français **Aristote**.

Pourquoi le *l* a été enlevé de l'écriture française ? En revanche,tous les autres mots (français) de la même famille que je connais (aristotélicien, aristotélique, aristotélisme, aristotéliser (Littré pour le dernier) gardent ce l.

Comment: Autant demander pourquoi le *l* en *table* est (normalement) silencieux :) Je pense que c'est le même processus à peu près.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Je suppose que c'est pour des raisons d'euphonie (il n'y a pas de mots français en ***-otle*** et la séquence ***-tl-*** est rare dans notre vocabulaire, en dehors d'atlantique, athtlète, atlas et dérivés) et peut-être aussi pour préserver l'accent tonique sur le *o* que l'on aurait perdu si l'on avait écrit *Aristotel*.

[L'ancien français](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aristotle#Ancien_fran%C3%A7ais) (plus précisément l'anglo-normand ici) a utilisé *Aristotle* :

> Primes saciez ke icest tretiez
>   est le secré de secrez numez
>   Ke Aristotle le philosophe ydoine
>   Le fiz Nichomache de Macedoine
>   — (Pierre d’Abernon, le secré des secrez, f. 173v. a., vers 1-4)

Beaucoup de langues ont supprimé le *es* final, seules deux sont allées plus loin que le français, le turc et le farsi avec ***[Aristo](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aristote#Voir_aussi)***.

La langue nahuatl, particulièrement riche en terminaisons en -tl car il s'agit du suffixe le plus courant de sa grammaire, a donné quelques mots largement adoptés par les langues occidentales via l'espagnol. On constate que le *l* final a disparu de la grande majorité de ces mots :

- *tomatl* - *tomato*/tomate
- *coyotl* - [coyote](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coyote)/*κογιότ*
- *xocoatl* ou *chicolātl* - *chocolate*/[chocolat](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chocolat)
- *ahuacatl* - *aguacate*/*avocado*/[avocat](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avocat/1)
- *ocelotl* - [ocelot](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ocelot)

Seuls quelques mots nahuatl, moins répandus, ont conservé leur terminaison :

- [*peyotl*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/peyotl)
- [*axolotl*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/axolotl)

Comment: À part les emprunts récents au nahuatl, toutes les séquences /tl/ en français sont séparées par une pause syllabique: atlas /at.las/, attelage /at.la:ʒ/, ôtes-les /o:t.lɛ/. Ce n'est pas le cas des séquences équivalentes comme /pl/, /kl/ qui peuvent très bien tenir en une seule syllable. Même chose avec le pendant voisé /dl/ qui est presque totalement absent. Ça renforce certainement l'hypothèse qu'Aristotle aurait produit une séquence inédite et phonotactiquement problématique, qui aurait alors été simplifiée en /t/. J'ai des doutes sur la pérennité du /tl/ d'axolotl pour cette raison